# swift (spritekit) - how to get callback after block / closure enumeration?

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, sprite-kit, block

I'm trying to do a check inside of an enumeration.  if my conditional statement is triggered, then i want to exit the parent function.   the problem is that i think this is happening asynchronously, so once in a while it will exit the function while the loop is still executing and cause a memory error.

```
    self.gameScene!.physicsWorld.enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart(self.position, end: randomPt, usingBlock: {
        body, point, normal, stop in

        if let node = body.node {
            // we're intersecting with the enemy.  lets try again
            if node.name != nil && node.name == "shieldBox" {
                abort = true
                stop.memory = true
            }
        }


    })

    // this sometimes causes an error.  the closure above is still executing!
    if abort {
        self.checkWayPoint()
        return
    }
```

i need to make sure enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart is finished before moving along.  is there any way to do this?  A regular loop alternative would be great too.. but cant find anything like that.

Comment: I'm fairly sure `enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart` is synchronous.  What's the exact error you're getting and is it on the `if abort` line, or is it on `self.checkWayPoint()`. If the later, what does that function do?

Comment: checkWayPoint is the name of the function youre looking at.  if we hit abort, i try calling this same function again.  this is the problem.  i guess causing the function recursively while this enumeration is going is a bad idea. the error is inside of the enumeration.  its a bad access memory error.

Comment: I see. What's the exact line the error occurs on in the enumeration block?

Comment: either if node.name != nil && node.name == "shieldBox"

or self.gameScene!.physicsWorld.enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart